# Finding img and click using alt locator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to find and click on a img on Amazon bookstore using alt to locate, but with only one word (the word "Game" in this case).

What I tried:

```
 describe 'test' do

it 'visit Amazon' do

    visit 'https://www.amazon.com/s/browse?_encoding=UTF8&node=283155&ref_=nav_shopall-export_nav_mw_sbd_intl_books'

        expect(page.find('#image')['alt']).to match(/Game/)

        puts 'ok'


end

end
```

The element on site:

```
<img onload="window.uet &amp;&amp; uet.call &amp;&amp; uet(&quot;cf&quot;);" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81VqkhMFpuL._AC_SR201,266_.jpg" alt="A Game of Thrones: A Song of Ice and Fire, Book 1" class="aok-align-center">
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find an img element by partial contents of its `alt` attribute you can use CSS attribute selectors lik

```
page.find('img[alt*="Game"]').click # alt attribute contains Game
page.find('img[alt~="Game"]').click # alt attribute contains the word Game
```

Another option, assuming the img is warpped by a link, would be to use the fact that click_link will (by default partial) match on the :alt attribute of a wrapped image - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_link-instance_method

```
page.click_link('Game')
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, it worked! But if I have more than one element with Game, how can I choose the first one? I tried page.find('img[alt~="Game[1]"]') but don't worked.

Comment: @holyonline `img[alt~="Game"]` is a CSS selector, it doesn't support indexing like that.  Easiest way to do what you what you're asking would just be to do `page.first('img[alt~="Game"]').click`, which is basically equivalent to `page.all('img[alt~="Game"]')[1].click`

Comment: Thanks again Thomas! Works perfectly!